# How to add quotes to symbol expansion in eclipse

Tags: macros, eclipse-cdt, symbols

I am working on a C/C++ project and have installed eclipse Oxygen CDT. My code uses some macros which are provided at run time using the `-D` tag of `gcc`. So I defined them under `Project Properties >> C/C++ General >> Paths and Symbols >> Symbols`.

In the code somewhere I have written:

```
char *address = DEFAULT_SETUP;
```

In the Symbols, I have defined `DEFAULT_SETUP` with a value `PREFIX/etc/PROJECT`, where `PREFIX` in-turn is valued as `/usr/local` and `PROJECT` has value `FirstC`.

Whenever I put my cursor on `DEFAULT_SETUP` and press `CMD+#` to see the macro expansion, I get the desired value as `/usr/local/etc/FirstC` but without quotes and thus the IDE cries and shows syntax error.

Now if I put quotes on the value of `DEFAULT_SETUP` as `"PREFIX/etc/PROJECT"` and expand the macro, I get the value as it is without the value of `PREFIX` and `PROJECT` replaced.

I also tried putting `${xx}` which expands the string but surround it like `${/usr/local/etc/FirstC}`.

I am getting frustrated as this is my first C/C++ project in Linux environment. Help will be really appreciated.